# Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I run ionic run android and it starts to download lots of things except `gradle` that i downloaded it and set the path myself, now i have 2 question:

**1:** Should ionic framework always download lots of things with every new project?

and

**2:** How i resolve the below error , i set `ANDROID_PATH` variable to point Android-SDK where packages exist

**What went wrong:**

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android':

```
 No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0
 or higher.
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer is yes (through Gradle) and you have to set `ANDROID_HOME` and then add to `PATH` based on this.

On the Mac I had much the same problem.  I was lacking the Android SDK.  I don't know if that was your problem.  I'll assume you don't have the SDK but you can pick up from your problem place in this list.

1. Download and install Android SDK for you platform. I'm on Mac so will present instructions from that perspective.
2. Go to `Configuration` on login splash screen or Preferences through File or Apple menu.
3. Go to `Appearance and Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK`
4. Observe the `Android SDK Location`.  Mine is `/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk`
5. Open `~/.profile`
6. Add `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk`
7. Add `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
8. Save and `source ~/.profile`

You could have the additional problem of not having Gradle installed.  Try:

1. Download the binary
2. Extract to `/usr/local` or wherever you can write (eg. `~/lib` where I install such things locally) if you don't have admin rights
3. sym link the version of gradle - `cd /usr/local;ln -s gradle-3.5 gradle`
4. Add `/usr/local/gradle` to your `$PATH` like above and `source ~/.profile` again.

I reread the question and realised I had added too much detail in my answer.  I believe the `$ANDROID_HOME` and path line is what you are missing.

You may also need to open Android Studio and do whatever configuration it requires.  And setup a SDK Platform also in that configuration window discussed above.

I hope that helps.